Finding stabilizers from a T distillation code
Consider $T$ state distillation as per Figure 14 in this paper.
I am trying to figure out what the stabilizers are. I thought of trying to evolve them starting from e.g. $S = XI\cdots I$ acting on the initial $|+ \cdots\rangle$ state, but due to the $T$ gate, the evolution is non-trivial.
In his answer to this post, for example, Craig Gidney mentioned that errors may combine as $3\oplus14=13$. This was in a different context, but I don't understand how to see it intuitively, or what kind of calculation I need to do to obtain the stabilizers and understand this equality.
One other thought was that maybe I should stop before the $T$ gate, but why would that make sense? The $T$ gate brings a non trivial operation, and I don't see how operators from the Pauli group can stabilize the states once $T$ has been applied to them.
While using an actual paper for reference, this is a question on a basic concept that I am failing to understand, in the context of a first course on quantum computing.
